# Laravel 5.1 routing not working except '/'

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

I have created a new laravel project in `/var/www/polyforms.me` and created virtual host file `polyforms.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName polyforms.dev

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/polyforms.me/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/polyforms.me-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/polyforms.me-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

When I go to `polyforms.dev` it opens home page as it should, but when I go to let's say `polyforms.dev/about` it shows me this:

[image]

If I use `php artisan serve` and use `http://localhost:8000/about` everything works fine... What is the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess .htaccess is ignored.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#allowoverride

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName polyforms.dev

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/polyforms.me/public

    <Directory "/var/www/polyforms.me/public">
      AllowOverride all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/polyforms.me-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/polyforms.me-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you have a .htaccess file in the web root that points everything to index.php? If not, that's the problem (see the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2#pretty-urls) on what to add where). If so, Apache may be configured to deny .htaccess overrides. In that case you'll need to add a  segment in your VirtualHost configuration allowing those. See the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) for more information. It also may be the case that mod_rewrite is not enabled. If using Ubuntu, Debian or other Debian-based OS is used a `sudo a2enmod rewrite` followed by `sudo service apache2 reload` will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You have .htaccess file in your public folder. So copy that into cpanel's root .htaccess file.