# Not able to view my laravel project on the browser

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I have installed laravel on a new EC2 instance and I have ensured that my php, Mysql and apache2 are all running

My Laravel version is 5.2.45

my 000-default.conf is as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/testing/public

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

my apache2.conf file is as follows

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/testing/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

my folder structure is /var/www/html/testing

But I am getting a 500 when trying to hit the ip..Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you run `php artisan serve`

Comment: Yes but then it does not work as I have my project on EC2 and serve gives me a localhost to check my code

Comment: did you enabled the ports in security groups in aws ec2 settings

Comment: give 777 permissions to  storage and bootstarp directory

Comment: I am able to access only / route and no other routes , so any idea where am I going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, give permissions to your logs files:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/testing/storage/
```

Comment: I am getting an error...file_put_contents(/var/www/html/testing/storage/framework/views/5b6b8c386effa98dcb94bc25d798a39157716c4b.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: I removed logs from the end and chmod the entire storage directory and get the Laravel screen

Comment: The problem is still my other routes are not working..any idea why?

Comment: I think this would help you.. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617251/laravel-5-1-routing-not-working-except